# What does the dot (number of points in row) mean in jmeter graph listener?

Tags: jmeter

I'm bit confused with the dot in graph of jmeter listener. Tried reading jmeter docs but no luck.

[image]

From the above, when I have 1 thread/user, graph display 11 dot. Does it mean 1 user submit 11 request in that time frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jp@gc - Hits per Second` shows the number of requests sent to the server by the test plan. It does not matter how many users your test plan has. If you have only 1 user, then, yes, it would have been sent by 1 user in that time frame.